# Weird output from GetDiskFreeSpace()

Tags: c++, winapi

I think I set up the GetDiskFreeSpace() function correct but my output does not look right.

```
#define wszDrive L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0"

DWORD dwSectPerClust,
        dwBytesPerSect,
        dwFreeClusters,
        dwTotalClusters;

    BOOL diskClust = 0;
    diskClust = GetDiskFreeSpace(wszDrive,
        &dwSectPerClust,
        &dwBytesPerSect,
        &dwFreeClusters,
        &dwTotalClusters);
    cout << "Sectors Per Cluster: " << dwSectPerClust << endl;
    cout << "Bytes Per Sector: " << dwBytesPerSect << endl;
    cout << "Free Clusters: " << dwFreeClusters << endl;
    cout << "Total Clusters: " << dwTotalClusters << endl;
```

I don't get any errors or warnings but when I build and run this is how my output looks completely wrong:

```
Sectors Per Cluster: 3435973836
Bytes Per Sector: 3435973836
Free Clusters: 3435973836
Total Clusters: 3435973836
```

I am not sure why the variables might already be initialized? I also added an if statement for error handling:

```
if (diskClust == 0){ cout << "GetDiskFreeSpace failed with error: "<<GetLastError() << endl; }
```

With an output of `GetDiskFreeSpace failed with error: 1`

Comment: `GetDiskFreeSpace` was really designed for much smaller drives than those we have today. Use [`GetDiskFreeSpaceEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364937.aspx) instead.

Comment: Roman R. is bang on. It looks like the call to `GetDiskFreeSpace` is failing and not putting anything in your DWORDs. Check the value of `diskClust`; it will likely indicate a failure.

Comment: Should the drive name really be in a `L"..."`?

Comment: Yea I checked the value of diskClust and got an error. How can I fix this issue? This is the first time I used the variables. I tried different variables and got the same output.

Comment: What is the error code?

Comment: if (diskClust == 0){ cout << "GetDiskFreeSpace failed with error: "<<GetLastError() << endl; }  Gives me 1

Comment: I don't think this should be called a duplicate. Yes the output is 0xccccccccc but that is not the real problem. I guess the OP can rephrase the question to ask why GetDiskFreeSpace() is failing and completly eliminate the 0xcccccccc from the discussion by just checking the return code like the comment above.

Comment: As to the **why** your call is failing, it's simply because you're using `\\.\PhysicalDrive0`, which isn't what's supposed to be used; you're supposed to use the drive mount point e.g. `c:`, or if you have it, the volume name e.g. `\\?\Volume{21d48af6-62f8-4236-b97d-a14eb1801a06}`, or if it's a UNC share `\\server\share`

Comment: @Petesh I replaced "\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0" with "C:" and it worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: It's amazing how many people ignore error checking. Don't do that.